# Create a String from other String in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop, compare

Given a String like this:
String secret = “H)86(e,@€l:-;l?,;5o” they ask me to make a new String with only the letters (and spaces if they are) to reveal a secret message….

I tried with a for loop and the charAt method, but it didn’t work… ideas?
I would appreciate plain explanation as I’m noob on programming.
Thanks!!

Comment: `secret = secret.replaceAll("\\W|\\d","");` output for this statement is `Hello`

Comment: For next time, SO can give you far better answers if you replace "I tried" with an actual paste of the code you ran and "it didn't work" with what happened (compile problem? Say that. Exception? Show the full trace. Result you did not expect? Show the result you wanted, and the result you actually got).

Comment: Ok, I’ll do it like that next time, this time it wasn’t possible,.Ty for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by a regular expression (`regex`) in `String#replaceAll(regexString, replaceString)`.

```
String decrypted = secret.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z ]", "");
```

This will find everything, except A to Z, a to z, space and will replace it by "" (nothing).

You can test such expressions here: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a regular expression that matches only letters and space?

like this: `"[a-zA-Z ]*"`

Answer (score 0):

Use a „regular expression“ (RegEx) and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- to strip out all unwanted characters.

Something like this will do:

```
var hello = "H)86(e,@€l:-;l?,;5o".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]","");
```